# Перегрузка оператора "+"

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сделать в своём классе перегрузку оператора `+`

Класс

```
class String{
    const char* nap;
    public:
        String operator+(const char* n) const{
            cout<<n;
        };
        String operator+(const String& s) const{
            cout<<s;
        };

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& str,const String& b){
            cout<<b.nap;
        }

};
```

В главной функции

```
int main(void) {
    String s = "To be" + String("1");
    cout<<s;
}
```

Получаю ошибку вида

> [Error] no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'const char [6]' and 'String')

Что я упустил ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы упускаете, что вы перегрузили поведение для

```
String operator+( const String& left, const char* const right );
```

но не для

```
String operator+(  const char* const left, const String& right );
```

И советы:

- оператор+ должен возвращать новый объект типа String - у вас такого нету
- операторы которые не влияют на внутреннее состояния класса должны перегружаться вне класса
- нужно перегрузить операторы в случаях если операнты оператора поменяются местами
- нужно перегрузить сокращенную форму
- Лучше всего вынести всё это дело в метод

  String add(const String& s);

тогда перегрузки будут такие:

```
return add(s);

return add(String(c_str));
```

Comment: как учесть случай когда нужно `String s = "To be" + String("1")+" text"; cout<<s;`
я просто подумал как в вашем ответе решил сделать функции как вы и указали , но тогда получаю ошибку `[Error] 'String String::operator+(const char*, const String&)' must take either zero or one argument`

Comment: «класса должны перегружаться глобально», не глобально, а вне класса, т.е. должны быть свободными функциями, а не методами.

Comment: @user2420249 вне класса

Comment: @ixSci согласен - исправил.